# How can MutationObservers be used to find when an element's parent is removed from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, custom-element, mutation-observers

My application has some [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) attached to DOM elements low down in the DOM tree. They need to detect when any one of their ancestors are removed from the DOM.

It's simple to use MutationObservers to detect if a particular element or any of its children are removed. However, what is the best way to determine if any of an elements parents are removed?

[Here is a plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/UsMiKDqxtPJnV0CCxJpF) that demonstrates the issue. In the plunker, notice that when you click "Remove Parent", the parent element's mutation observer is invoked. However, the child element's observer is not.

How can I *efficiently* use MutationObservers to check when a node is removed from the document?

---

**Edit**

My use case is that I have implemented some web components that need to invoke clean up code when they (or one of their parents) are removed from the DOM. I want each web component to be encapsulated so that it handles its own clean up and there is no global registry (other than the native `window.customElements`).

Comment: Your title is the opposite of your question.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in the child observer. You need to detect it in the parent, then you can use `elementBeingRemoved.contains(child)` to test if the child is affected.

Comment: AFAIK, MutationObserver only watches after children.  Why can't you observe from closer to the root of the DOM?  Also, what is your use case?  It seems you know nodes will be removed... controlling this from the removal mechanism is almost certainly a better answer than watching with MutationObserver.

Comment: @McHat, I do realize that MutationObservers are not meant to do this directly, but I'm trying to figure out what the best approach is. I'll update the question with a use case for this.

Comment: @Barmar, you're right that my question is confusing. I'll update that, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your implementing your web components from scratch, you should use the native [**lifecycle callbacks**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks). In your case, the `disconnectedCallback` would be the one to trigger your clean up code inside the component.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. Let me try it out.